# Does torify/torsocks give access to hidden services?

Tags: torsocks, torify

Most `torify` documentation is about accessing non-hidden services.

Yet .onion address look like real tcp addresses, does `torify` make those available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The torsocks program (the actual name of the torify alias) can connect to hidden services fine. For example:

```
torsocks curl https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion
```

Comment: Need small clarification: My executable needs to connects to services on the local network. Will those connections still work?

Comment: If you use torsocks, it will not allow you to connect to services on the local network for safety reasons. If that's what you want to do, you might find proxychains helpful (using the `localnet` option).

Comment: I got `curl` to work in 3 modes: torsocks, proxychains, and privproxy with curl --proxy option. Yet, for some reason my executable does not connect to the onion address in any of those modes.

Comment: What executable are you using? torsocks does not work for all executables. The problem is probably DNS related, so you might want to look into the `MapAddress` torrc option to map the onion name to an IP address. For example something like `MapAddress 192.0.2.10 qwerty.onion`, and then `torsocks curl 192.0.2.10`.

Comment: MapAddress also works for `curl` yet not for my executable (which is https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus ) - it seems to ignore `torsocks` - and works for regular addresses but not for `192.0.2.10`

Comment: @AleksandrLevchuk Torsocks (and proxychains) uses symbol interposition to intercept glibc calls. If you're using a program that doesn't dynamically link to glibc (such as Go programs), torsocks won't work and any network requests will bypass Tor.

Answer (score 1):

If the hidden service is HTTP **AND** your client for some reason does not support torsocks, then you may benefit from a [nginx revers proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) listening on local ports

WARNINGS:

- This nginx process will not be listen on 0.0.0.0 because it's torified. It will only listen to localhost (127.0.0.1). This is good because on 0.0.0.0 you may be reachable on a public port and will become proxy to the hidden service for anyone on the non-tor Internet.
- Every user on the operating system will get access to the hidden service

1. Edit `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:1234 default_server;

    location / {
       proxy_pass https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion;

       # Timeout
       proxy_connect_timeout       5m;
       proxy_send_timeout          5m;
       proxy_read_timeout          5m;
       send_timeout                5m;

       # Settings for cache
       proxy_set_header       Host $host;
       proxy_buffering        on;
       proxy_cache            STATIC;
       proxy_cache_valid      200  5m;
       proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
                              http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     }
}
```

2. Edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
http {

    ## 2021-01-01
    proxy_cache_path  /opt/nginx/cache  levels=1:2
    keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=24h  max_size=1g;
```

3. Run:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/nginx/
```

4. Start nginx in torifyed mode:

```
sudo torsocks nginx
```

5. Now you can use regular local HTTP connections, e.g.:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:1234
```

To stop, use regular kill because systemctl will not work:

```
ps axf | grep -v grep | grep nginx  # lookup PID

kill PID_GOES_HERE
```

## Let nginx restart automatically (systemd)

Now instead of starting and stopping ngingx manually, edit systemd script so it does it automatically every time the process crashes or the system reboots.

Edit `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`

- Simply add `/usr/bin/torsocks` in front of every Exec command
- So Exec commands should looks similar to this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/torsocks /usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/bin/torsocks /usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=/usr/bin/torsocks /sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
```

1. Make script changes effective: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
2. Manually kill your current nginx
3. `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

## Historical details

- "Connection timed out" in /var/log/nginx/error.log
  and all connections to the onion address stop working. Restarting tor for the client mitigates the issue temporarily. To to prevent the issue I increased the connection timeout and added caching for 5 minutes.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might find socat easier to use. For example, `/usr/bin/socat TCP-LISTEN:1234,fork SOCKS4A:127.0.0.1:3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion:80,socksport=9050`